# Adding specific column by getting column in other table

Tags: mysql

My problem is merging this two tables into 1, having the parent table is tbl1.

```
tbl1
userid | Checkin | checkout

tbl2
userid | Name | Department
```

I run this, and come up with an error

> "ambiguous field list"

```
SELECT userid, checkin, checkout
from tbl1
join tbl2
on tbl1.userid = tbl2.userid
order by tbl1.userid
```

I want my table to like this:

```
userid | Checkin | checkout | Name | Deparment
```

Comment: Both tables have column userid, so you have to specify the table or table alias along with the SELECT columns.(tbl1.userid or tbl2.userid )

Comment: what if, i only want is the NAME column to be added in the tbl1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both tables have column `userid`, so you have to specify the table or table alias along with the selected columns.(tbl1.userid or tbl2.userid )

```
SELECT tbl1.userid, checkin, checkout, Name, Department 
from tbl1
join tbl2
on tbl1.userid = tbl2.userid
order by tbl1.userid
```

Comment: i already run this but still only tbl1 appears but no column Name and Department, nway thanks for the reply..

Comment: SELECT tbl1.userid, checkin, checkout, Name, Department FROM ...  query edited, plz chk

Answer (score 1):

Try this;)

```
SELECT tbl1.userid, checkin, checkout, Name, Department
from tbl1
join tbl2
on tbl1.userid = tbl2.userid
order by tbl1.userid
```